# Quip Personal Live app sdk

Tags: quip, liveapps

I would love to develop live apps for quip, but I only have a personal edition. Does anyone know if there are plans to open the SDK up for personal development? Or Developer Orgs?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, live apps are available only for organizations and we do not have plans to enable it in the short or medium-term. However, you can easily create an organization for yourself and try it out for free (we have a free trial for any organization).